# Perform cost distance with horizontal factors of varying magnitude

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, cost-path, cost-surface

I am using ArcGIS Pro, I want to create a path-distance map for movement through water, factoring in ocean current direction and also magnitude. I have raster layers with the ocean currents in each cell expressed in terms of their northwards and eastwards components, and I also have a 2-band raster with these components combined to give direction and magnitude. I cannot seem to be able to use the magnitude of the ocean current when using the path-distance analysis tool.

I am wondering how I can incorporate both the direction and magnitude, as the speed of the current is important?

Comment: I would imagine these type of raster processing tools take as input *single-band* rasters.  You need to use the make raster layer tool to extract out a single bands worth of data and feed that into the cost path tool.